# Multile upload to folders

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

I am trying to upload multiple files by creating a folder according to the serial number and saving the files in them. My codes are as below :

**HTML Code for Multiple Uploads:**

```
 <div class="form-inline clearfix">
            <label class="col-md-5">Select A File To Upload:</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="Uploaded_file" multiple="multiple"/> 
                </div>
 </div><br/>
```

**PHP Code for Multiple Uploads**

```
if (count($_FILES["myfile"]) > 0)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]); $i++) 
    {
        foreach ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"][$i] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

                $structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/$formno"; //FormNo is the serial number queried from the database
                if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))
                {
                    die('Failed to create folders...');
                }
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i][$key];
                $name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i][$key];
                $target = $target .'/' .$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i] ; 
                $filepath=$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i] ;
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$structure/$name")) 
                { 
                    echo "<center>The file ". basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]). " has been uploaded.</center>"; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    echo "No File was uploaded"; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I upload multiple files, only the last file is being saved in the directory. How can I modify my code so that I can upload multiple files?
Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select#Multiple_file_selection). Example (PHP 5.4):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="Filename">
            <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
                $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                $Filename=$_POST['Filename'];
                $structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/$Filename";
                if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))
                {
                 die('Failed to create folders...');
                }

                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                $name = $_FILES["my_file"]["name"][$i];
                $tmp_name=$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$structure/$name");
                    ?>
                        <p>File #<?= $i+1 ?>:</p>
                        <p>
                            Name: <?= $myFile["name"][$i] ?><br>
                            Temporary file: <?= $myFile["tmp_name"][$i] ?><br>
                            Type: <?= $myFile["type"][$i] ?><br>
                            Size: <?= $myFile["size"][$i] ?><br>
                            Error: <?= $myFile["error"][$i] ?><br>
                        </p>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's what it looks like in Chrome after selecting 2 items in the file dialog:

[image: chrome multiple file select]

And here's what it looks like after clicking the "Upload" button.

[image: submitting multiple files to PHP]

This is just a sketch of a fully working answer. See [PHP Manual: Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information on proper, secure handling of file uploads in PHP.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I want to know how to upload multiple files into the created directory. At the moment, only one file is uploading.

Comment: just add move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"][$i], ","$structure/$name"); in the above code inside for loop.